# Python merge sort

Tags: python, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm new to python. I can't understand how the program gets directed back to mergeSort after "print("Merging ",alist)". Can anybody explain this? thanks

```
  def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
3    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

8      mergeSort(lefthalf)
9      mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
32     print("Merging ",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: You mean you wonder why `print(alist)` is executed after `print("Merging ",alist)`? Why would it *not* do that?

Comment: Maybe the Wikipedia article on [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) will be helpful...

Comment: I tried adding line numbers above. I see why the program goes to line 32 after the if statement in line 3. However, why does it move to line 9 after line 32? thanks

Comment: Your `mergeSort` function is recursive. In line 8, it calls itself. That secondary call to `mergeSort` reaches line 32 and returns. Then the program continues in line 9.

Answer (score 0):

when i run your program i get:

```
('Splitting ', [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20])
('Splitting ', [54, 26, 93, 17])
('Splitting ', [54, 26])
('Splitting ', [54])
('Merging ', [54])
('Splitting ', [26])
('Merging ', [26])
('Merging ', [26, 54])
('Splitting ', [93, 17])
('Splitting ', [93])
('Merging ', [93])
('Splitting ', [17])
('Merging ', [17])
('Merging ', [17, 93])
('Merging ', [17, 26, 54, 93])
('Splitting ', [77, 31, 44, 55, 20])
('Splitting ', [77, 31])
('Splitting ', [77])
('Merging ', [77])
('Splitting ', [31])
('Merging ', [31])
('Merging ', [31, 77])
('Splitting ', [44, 55, 20])
('Splitting ', [44])
('Merging ', [44])
('Splitting ', [55, 20])
('Splitting ', [55])
('Merging ', [55])
('Splitting ', [20])
('Merging ', [20])
('Merging ', [20, 55])
('Merging ', [20, 44, 55])
('Merging ', [20, 31, 44, 55, 77])
('Merging ', [17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93])
[17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
```

## Splitting :

Here is the analysis:

1) your array is first taken into alist

2) left half of the array is then split and taken as alist

3) left half of that is agian taken as alist

4) now your alist is 54

Once you figure this out, see tha same pattern done again to the right half.

It is recursion.

## Merging :

1) the very core of merge sort, merging of 2 arrays.

2) at every stage 2 arrays are merged.

3) merging of 2 arrays is done every time the splitting goes all the way down to single element.

Hope this helps. To learn more check out youtube video on merge sort.

Comment: I tried adding line numbers above. I see why the program goes to line 32 after the if statement in line 3. However, why does it move to line 9 after line 32? thanks

Comment: good question: that happens because the function that calls left half returns. and then the function that calls right half executes. (Its how merge sort works)

Comment: no dont change the code. i am saying that the programs line which calls "mergesort(lefthalf)" completes execution. at line 32 when it get down to single element. then it returns to line 9 and calls mergesort(righthalf). Since this is recursion it is important to know how deep a call you are at when the function returns.